# What is this object?

Tags: electrical-engineering, mechanical

In framing the question, I can't be more specific as I have no idea (though a suspicion) about what this came from.

[image]

I have a number of them that are several different diameters from 125mm to about 300mm.

They are very thin steel (< 1mm) and each size came in a tight stack, as though laminated.  They don't seem to have been glued together as they come apart easily.  We have had them for about 20 years.  Note the notch at 7 o'clock possibly to align or secure a stack.

I suspect they are part of some sort of electrical winding, but I would have thought they would have "teeth" on the outside.

Any ideas what they came from?

Nowadays they are part of an art project.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Silicone steel stamped lamination, stator and rotor. Image source:[HS Magnets](https://www.hsmagnets.com/product/silicon-steel-stamped-lamination-stator-and-rotor/)*

[image]

*Figure 2. On their way to becoming motors.*

Comment: Ahhh...as I suspected.  Thanks!